# Way To Check Next Case After Fall Through In Switch Statement?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any way to check the next case after a `fallthrough` in Swift? It seems like it would be a great way to write concise code.

```
    case 1...8:

        self.correctAnswerLabelOne.text = answerLabelOne?.firstObject as? String
        self.correctAnswerLabelOne.alpha = 0.0
        self.correctAnswerLabelOne.hidden = false
        self.fadeAnimation(self.correctAnswerLabelOne, duration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, alpha: 1.0, options: .CurveEaseIn)

        fallthrough

    case 2...8:

        self.correctAnswerLabelTwo.text = answerLabelTwo?.firstObject as? String
        self.correctAnswerLabelTwo.alpha = 0.0
        self.correctAnswerLabelTwo.hidden = false
        self.fadeAnimation(self.correctAnswerLabelTwo, duration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, alpha: 1.0, options: .CurveEaseIn)

        fallthrough

    case 3...8:

        self.correctAnswerLabelThree.text = answerLabelThree?.firstObject as? String
        self.correctAnswerLabelThree.alpha = 0.0
        self.correctAnswerLabelThree.hidden = false
        self.fadeAnimation(self.correctAnswerLabelThree, duration: 0.3, delay:     0.0, alpha: 1.0, options: .CurveEaseIn)
```

If the `case` is 3: Instead of having to add the code from `case 1` and `case 2` to `case 3` I would like to activate the first case, the second case, and then the third case. I could use an `if-statement` inside of each case but that doesn't seem like the best way. Is there another type of control-flow that would suit this purpose better or is it just necessary to copy the code all the way through?

Inside of a switch, `continue`, to me, seems to be a logical candidate to trigger the Switch to continue about it's business of checking case statements.

**UPDATE**:

Adding an `if-statement` to the presuppose the `fallthrough` gets the job done. It's still less "elegant" than I would expect but it works...

```
    switch(numberOfAnswers) {

    case 1...8:

        self.correctAnswerLabelOne.text = answerLabelOne?.firstObject as? String
        self.correctAnswerLabelOne.alpha = 0.0
        self.correctAnswerLabelOne.hidden = false
        self.fadeAnimation(self.correctAnswerLabelOne, duration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, alpha: 1.0, options: .CurveEaseIn)

        if numberOfAnswers > 1 {

            fallthrough

        }

    case 2...8:

        self.correctAnswerLabelTwo.text = answerLabelTwo?.firstObject as? String
        self.correctAnswerLabelTwo.alpha = 0.0
        self.correctAnswerLabelTwo.hidden = false

        self.fadeAnimation(self.correctAnswerLabelTwo, duration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, alpha: 1.0, options: .CurveEaseIn)

        if numberOfAnswers > 2 {

            fallthrough

        }
```

Comment: probably best to just get rid of the switch and just make each case an if statement instead

Comment: It would be almost the exact same code. I started writing it as an `if-statement` and then remembered `fallthrough` existed so I went to switch. I did not remember that `fallthrough` didn't check the next case.

Comment: let me see if i understand your problem: when the value is 1 - you execute code-for-#1, when value is 2 - you execute code-for-#1 and code-for-#2 then when it's 3 you execute code-for-#1, code-for-#2 and code-for-#3?

Comment: @RYUX123 Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would your code work if the switch statement was reversed? eg

```
switch(numberOfAnswers) {

case 2...8:

    self.correctAnswerLabelTwo.text = answerLabelTwo?.firstObject as? String
    self.correctAnswerLabelTwo.alpha = 0.0
    self.correctAnswerLabelTwo.hidden = false

    self.fadeAnimation(self.correctAnswerLabelTwo, duration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, alpha: 1.0, options: .CurveEaseIn)

    if numberOfAnswers > 2 {

        fallthrough

    }

case 1...8:

    self.correctAnswerLabelOne.text = answerLabelOne?.firstObject as? String
    self.correctAnswerLabelOne.alpha = 0.0
    self.correctAnswerLabelOne.hidden = false
    self.fadeAnimation(self.correctAnswerLabelOne, duration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, alpha: 1.0, options: .CurveEaseIn)

    if numberOfAnswers > 1 {

        fallthrough

    }
```

then it doesnt really matter about the evaluation of each case since the case above's range is contained within the case below's range anyway

Comment: Oh wow, that's good. Like a cascading waterfall. You can even remove the `if-statement`.  **clap emoji

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `self.correctAnswerLabelOne`, `correctAnswerLabelTwo` and so on, make a list of these labels so that you can address them as `self.correctAnswerLabel[i]`.  If these are individually laid out in Interface Builder then you can set up that array during `viewDidLoad`.

Once they're in a list, all this logic gets much easier.  You'd be able to do something like:

```
for (idx, label) in self.correctAnswerLabel.enumerate() {
    if idx > numberOfAnswers {
       // Hide label
    }
    else {
       // Show label
    }
}
```